# Laravel belongsTo & hasMany relation not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a table called `champ_sales` which contains champions that belong to table `champions`. I've set up my models properly, and I'm trying to query in the exact same way the documentation here: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations states, but it's not working.

```
class ChampSales extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'champ_sales';

    public function champ(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Champion');
    }

}
```

```
class Champion extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'champions';

    public function skins(){
        return $this->hasMany('Skin');
    }

//relevent relation here:
    public function championOnSale(){
        return $this->hasMany('ChampSales');
    }

    public function skinOnSale(){
        return $this->hasMany('SkinSales');
    }

}
```

My query: Find `start_date` in table `champions` for `id=2`

```
$champsales = ChampSales::find(2);
echo $champsales->champ->start_date;
```

Running this gives me a vague error that says "Trying to get property of non-object". I'm not really sure what I've done wrong, followed the documentation to the dot.

Comment: do you have any column "champion_id" in your `champ_sales` table?

Comment: Yes I do, infact I just solved it. I'm going to edit the post in a second. I defined the local and foreign key inside the champ() function and it fixed the problem. I'm not sure why that worked, because the naming convention still follows what laravel looks for.

Answer (score 2):

I just fixed it. I defined the local key and foreign key in champ(). I thought the laravel naming convention would pick that up fine, but I guess not.

```
class ChampSales extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'champ_sales';

    public function champ(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Champion', 'champion_id', 'id');
    }

}
```